# imagejpeg does not compress image file

Tags: php, resize, compression, imagejpeg

I would like to compress image file uploaded by users. However, the size of the image file after imagejpeg is the same size before imagejpeg.

Could you tell me why?

```
function compressImage($files_picture){
   $file_type = $files_picture['type']; // image/jpeg
   $original_picture_info =getimagesize($files_picture['tmp_name']);
   $original_picture_width = $original_picture_info[0];
   $original_picture_height = $original_picture_info[1];
   $new_picture_width = 400;
   $new_picture_height = 400;
   $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($new_picture_width, $new_picture_height);



    if($file_type == 'image/jpeg'){
        $original_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($files_picture['tmp_name']);
        imagecopyresampled($canvas, $original_image, 0,0,0,0, $new_picture_width, $new_picture_height, $original_picture_width, $original_picture_height);
        imagedestroy($original_image);
        imagejpeg($canvas, $files_picture['tmp_name'], 30);
    }elseif($file_type == 'image/png'){
        $original_image = imagecreatefrompng($files_picture['tmp_name']);
        imagecopyresampled($canvas, $original_image, 0,0,0,0, $new_picture_width, $new_picture_height, $original_picture_width, $original_picture_height);
        imagedestroy($original_image);
        imagepng($canvas, $files_picture['tmp_name'], 30);
    }elseif($file_type == 'imagegif'){
        $original_image = imagecreatefromgif($files_picture['tmp_name']);
        imagecopyresampled($canvas, $original_image, 0,0,0,0, $new_picture_width, $new_picture_height, $original_picture_width, $original_picture_height);
        imagedestroy($original_image);
        imagegif($canvas, $files_picture['tmp_name'], 30);
    }
    imagedestroy($canvas);
    return $files_picture;
}
```

Comment: Your script works (on my computer).

Comment: Was that picture really compressed?

Comment: Yes, the jpeg image size has changed to 400x400 and the quality has been compressed to 30%.

Comment: I will try to confirm again, thank you!

Comment: I think you should move the uploaded files with [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/de/function.move-uploaded-file.php) first. Because else it cause some permission issues if you write into the temp directory.